# How to track the previous Urls in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a main page which has a few filters that I want to keep when I return to this main url. But after loading another pages I want to go back. It could be easily done by getting the `@Request.UrlReferrer`. However, it only works when returning to the previous page, I need it for the previous 2 pages.

I could do it by using `Session["ReturnToMainUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer` but setting it only when getting off the first page.

So If I have 3 levels:

1. WebSite\page1?Filter=ABC
2. WebSite\page2
3. Website\page3
4. I am on page2 or page3 now and I want to go back to Website\page1?Filter=ABC

When I am on the page 3 I can use `Request.UrlReferrer` to go back to **page 2**, but when I go back to **page 1** I need to keep the parameters so I am loading from the Session.

How can I do it in a smarter way, not using sessions?

Comment: use a parameter `returnUrl` and pass it on across the pages you want to return from. In your case you have to pass it from `page1 -> page2->page3` . On page3 now redirect to the returnUrl

Comment: This may be applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402684/create-breadcrumbs-path-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yeah, however, from page3 it only goes to page2, so I can use the urlrefferer.. the only problem is when back to page 2 going to page1. So I think it is too bad to pass twice the returnUrl :(. @Ruchan

Comment: @BrendanGreen It is slighly different from that question, that is like killing a mosquito with a gun, I need some good practice in a simple way.

Comment: there is no harm in passing the returnUrl multiple times. If you don't feel ease with the method then other might be to use `session` or `cookie`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recursively build onto a `returnUrl` query string parameter as you progress from page to page.

For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtoX6b

```
var page0 = new Uri("http://www.example.com/page0");
Console.WriteLine("Page 0: {0}", page0);

var page1 = new Uri("http://www.example.com/page1?paramA=foo&paramB=bar&returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(page0.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine("Page 1: {0}", page1);

var page2 = new Uri("http://www.example.com/page2?paramC=baz&paramD=qux&returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(page1.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine("Page 2: {0}", page2);


var page2ReturnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(page2.Query)["returnUrl"];
Console.WriteLine("Return to page 1 from page 2: {0}", page2ReturnUrl);

var page1ReturnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(page1.Query)["returnUrl"];
Console.WriteLine("Return to page 0 from page 1 : {0}", page1ReturnUrl);
```

---

```
Page 0: http://www.example.com/page0
Page 1: http://www.example.com/page1?paramA=foo&paramB=bar&returnUrl=http:%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fpage0
Page 2: http://www.example.com/page2?paramC=baz&paramD=qux&returnUrl=http:%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fpage1%3fparamA%3dfoo%26paramB%3dbar%26returnUrl%3dhttp:%252f%252fwww.example.com%252fpage0

Return to page 1 from page 2: http://www.example.com/page1?paramA=foo&paramB=bar&returnUrl=http:%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fpage0
Return to page 0 from page 1 : http://www.example.com/page0
```

This could go on for many levels deep, yet the process for deriving the previous page's URL is always the same -- simply decode the `returnUrl` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, it work's.

ClassIndex Model:

> public class ClassIndex {    public int Id { get; set; } }

View:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<body>

    <a href="/Home/Back/">Back</a>
    <br />
    <a href="/Home/Index/1">Index 1 </a> | <a href="/Home/Index/2">Index 2 </a> | <a href="/Home/Index/3">Index 3 </a>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

Index.cshtml

> @model MvcApplication1.Models.ClassIndex @{
>       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
>       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
>
> ### Index @Model.Id

Home Controller

> public class HomeController : Controller
>       {
>           string key = "ItemKey";
>
> ```
>     public ActionResult Index(ClassIndex idx)
>     {
>         return View(idx);
>     }
>
>     public ActionResult Back()
>     {
>         var pageNumber = getPageUrl();
>         if (pageNumber == "/") pageNumber = "1";
>
>         return View("Index", 
>              new ClassIndex { Id = Convert.ToInt32(pageNumber) });
>     }
>
>     string getPageUrl()
>     {
>         Dictionary<int, string> items = (Dictionary<int, string>)ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items[key];
>         var lastItem = items.LastOrDefault();
>         var returnUrl = lastItem.Value;
>         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "1";
>
>         items.Remove(lastItem.Key);
>
>         return returnUrl.Replace("/Index/", "");
>     }
> }
> ```

Global.asax

Delcare this variables.

> IDictionary indexes = new Dictionary();  int
>   counter = 0;

Application_BeginRequest:
The event occurs when new request is triggred.

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var key = "ItemKey";
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("Back"))
            {
                indexes.Add(++counter, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace("/Home", ""));
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = indexes;
        }
```

Comment: Apart from using the javascript code history.go(-1), this solution gives more control to the functionality.